# What is the proper way to read numeric data (saved in a text file) into python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, text-files, readline

I have some information of coordinates of patches that need to be saved for further processing. I saved the coordinates (lists) into a files `patch_info.txt`, and data is like this for one file, that i append the information in a for loop for each mat file into text file:

```
[[117, 90, 75, 102, 105, 132],
  [117, 83, 68, 102, 98, 132],
  [117, 82, 67, 102, 97, 132],
  [116, 73, 58, 101, 88, 131],
  [115, 67, 52, 100, 82, 130],
  [112, 129, 114, 97, 144, 127],
  [110, 97, 82, 95, 112, 125],
  [109, 55, 40, 94, 70, 124],
  [102, 93, 78, 87, 108, 117],
  [99, 134, 119, 84, 149, 114],
  [96, 117, 102, 81, 132, 111],
  [96, 72, 57, 81, 87, 111],
  [82, 126, 111, 67, 141, 97],
  [78, 110, 95, 63, 125, 93]],
 'labels-001-012.mat']
```

and I used the following code to read them again into python:

```
patch_info=[]
with open('patch_info.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line=line.strip('\n')
        patch_info.append(ast.literal_eval(line))
```

My question is that some users do not suggest to use `ast.literal_eval`, what is the best way to read the numeric list of data into python?

Comment: Why not just read them into python the normal way and convert from string to int/float or whatever you need?

Comment: What have you seen are people's concerns with `ast.literal_eval`?  It may not be the most traditional way of unserializing data, but I don't see any real issue with it if it works for you (and whether it works will depend on how you've serialized it).

Comment: @data83 I followed your suggestion with this command, `patch_info=map(int,patch_info)`, however, I am getting an error `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10`

Comment: @jedwards indeed, `ast` is working for me, but I wanted to check if there is any other better ways. Thanks

Comment: @sc241 please show us what the data in your file looks like. Sounds like you are reading in strings without converting to numerical type.

Comment: @data83 i edited the question

Comment: @sc241 what is your expected output?

Comment: I think you are generating the text file in an odd way. Surely you can do it with space and line separation without the other junk brackets and commas. That way it would be a lot easier for you to read the lines into lists which then can easily be converted to an array. It all depends on what your expected output is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can format the data in textfile as json data, then you use `json.load` to parse the data. This is much better than using `ast.literal_eval`
If your data is not already formatted, you can use some preprocessing using `sed`/`awk` or something similar to convert it into the needed json format

For example, consider the following data in a file named test.data

```
[
[1,2],
[6,7],
[1,2],
[6,7],
[1,2],
[6,7],
[1,2],
[6,7],
[1,2],
[6,7]
]
```

Then you can load them in python by doing

```
>>> with open('test.data2', 'r') as f:
...     data = json.load(f)
... 
>>> data
[[1, 2], [6, 7], [1, 2], [6, 7], [1, 2], [6, 7], [1, 2], [6, 7], [1, 2], [6, 7]]
>>>
```

Comment: Why is it "much better"?

Comment: The question wasn't really answered